# Webpack require.ensure check load finish

Tags: webpack, lazy-loading, code-splitting

Webpack lazy loading can sometimes cause blank screens or delayed appearance of a component so I want to at least show a spinner so that users will not think we have a broken page.

Can `require.ensure` check if module loading is finished?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but you can use `=== undefined` like this:

```js
let Launcher;
require.ensure(['react-chat-window'], function (require) {
    Launcher = require('react-chat-window/lib/components/Launcher.js')
}, "modal-chat");
```

```js
if (Launcher === undefined){
    // ... doSomething here
}
```

For example, I used a state from React:

```js
if (Launcher !== undefined){
    this.setState({chatModuleLoaded: true})
}
```

Comment: This is an old question. I believe with today's power of webpack and react, this can be solve using React lazy and React Suspense.